# Multithread or Multiprocess Matplotlib plt.plot() Function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm currently working in Python using matplotlib to plot data to a figure using a for loop. The loop loops through sets of data and grabs a new 'x' and 'y' each time and then uses `plt.plot(x,y)` to plot that x and y data and then adds the plot to the current figure; I end up with multiple plots all placed over each other in a single figure.

Ex)

```
x_data_arr = [[11,5,4], [2,5,1], ...]   #list of lists containing x data points
y_data_arr = [[2,7,3], [9,2,6], ...]    #list of lists containing y data points

plt.figure(num='fig1')    #establish figure to plot to
for q in range(0, 100):
   x = x_data_arr[q]     #get x data (list of x data points)
   y = y_data_arr[q]     #get y data (list of x data points)
   plt.plot(x,y)         #plot this x and y to fig1 and restart loop to get/plot next x and y dataset

plt.show()  #shows all plots over one another on a single figure
```

I'm looking to improve the performance of continuously calling `plt.plot()`, as `plt.plot()` is currently blocking the for loop from continuing until the plot is finished which is very timely when there are a lot of plots to loop through and would be quicker if all the `plt.plot()`'s could be carried out concurrently

With that, is there a way I can use multithreading or multiprocessing to carry out each `plt.plot()` on a different thread or processor? I'm not too versed on the syntax of multiprocessing which I beleive may be the better option here in the instance matplotlib isn't threadsafe (yet that might not be concern since each plot is different)

Any help would be appreciated!